# Debug corefile without symbols

Tags: gdb, core-file

context: my program is running on server, which is compiled without debug option(hard to change that config).

I get the corefile which doesn't contain the symbol, and I have the source code(unfortunately error cannot be reproduced locally).

I know `strip`(https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) can remove symbols from ELF. Is there a tool can add them back?

Comment: What does the title `corefile without corefile` mean?

Comment: Sorry typo. "corefile without symbols"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a tool can add them back?

No, but you can give GDB a binary *with* debug symbols instead of the binary which actually produced the `core`.

The best practice is to *always* build with debug symbols, e.g. `gcc -g -O2 foo.c -o foo-g`, *keep* this `foo-g for future debugging, but ship to production a stripped binary:` strip -g -o foo foo-g`.

When you get a `core` from production, simply use `gdb foo-g core`, and you will have a much easier time debugging.

---

But let's assume you didn't follow the best practice, and built your binary with `gcc -O2 foo.c -o foo`. Can you do anything to recover debug info?

With `gcc` (and `g++`), you should be able to. Simply rebuild the application from *exactly* the same sources, using *exactly* the same command-line flags, but appending `-g`. Use newly-built binary to debug the `core`.

If you used `clang`, this procedure will probably not work, because `clang` doesn't produce identical code with and without `-g`.